# sort boxplot at factor (iris, R, ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to sort boxplot.
'left is tall box' and 'right is not tall'

```
ggplot(data = iris ,aes(x = Species,y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_violin(fill='gray')
```

I did this code, setosa:left and virginica:right.
but max(Sepal.Width) each Species, Versicolor is the least.
I want to sort setosa-virginica-versicolor reference to max(Sepal.Width).

Comment: The question has come up in earlier threads. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/43221332/6503141 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494457/6503141 or the use of `xlim` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464682/6503141 or generally searching for ggplot order boxplot should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this. You can use `reorder()` with the option `FUN` enabled. In this case you can use `max`, if I understand you correctly. I have included two options:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code 1
ggplot(data = iris ,aes(x = reorder(Species,Sepal.Width,FUN = max),y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_violin(fill='gray')+xlab('Species')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(data = iris ,aes(x = reorder(Species,-Sepal.Width,FUN = max),y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_violin(fill='gray')+xlab('Species')
```

Output:

[image]